# one-to-one relationship in Ormlite

Tags: ormlite

I got the following classes I want to save in the DB with Ormlite:

```
public class Quantity {
    private int normalisedAmount; 
    private String unit;
    ....
}

public class Article {
    private String name;  
    private Quantity q;
    ....
}
```

The thing is that there is a one-to-one relationship between Quantity and Article. One way to use Ormlite is to make q foreign like:

```
@DatabaseField(foreign = true)
private Quantity q;
```

The drawback is that the DB will not be [normilazed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

One other solution is to make a [Custom Data Type by create a Persister](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_5.html#SEC57). The problem there is that you either have to serialize the Quantity object or put the fileds "name" and "q" into the same DB column. None of them looks nice.

How do I make a nice looking solotion?

Comment: That's true but isn't the table for Quantity still created in the DB? If so, the DB is not normilazed, right?

Comment: I've moved my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get one-to-one relationship, you could you put a `unique` constraint on the `q` field.  I've not tried it but it should limit the number of rows with the `q.name` field to 1.

This *will* create a `Quantity` table which (I believe) is how other ORMs do it.  I don't think this violates database "normalization".  Your `Article` table has a single field in it which represents the id of the `Quantity` -- not sure what the id field is there.  All of the rest of the fields from `Quantity` will be in the other table.

The alternative would be to embed `Quantity` into `Article` which [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) does not support.

Comment: I guess that is the best solution we got even if one-to-one relationships in databases is nothing to be happy about.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with letting the Quantity object blend in the Article and add a getQuantity-method. Now the 1-to-1 relation is gone in the DB.

```
public class Article {
    private String name;  
    // Quantity
    private int normalisedAmount; 
    private String unit;
    ....

    Quantity getQuantity() {
         return new Quantity(normalisedAmount, unit);
    }
}
```